# Map through an inner array of an Object

Tags: javascript

I have this object:

```
let arr = [{  
    id : 1,
    usr : 'pimba',
    xyz: null
  },
  {
    id  : 2,
    usr : 'aloha',
    xyz: {
     xyz_id: 2      
    }    
  },
  {
    id  : 3,
    age : 'pruu',
    xyz: null
  }];
```

As you can notice, sometimes `xyz` is null and sometimes it's not.
I need to recognize whether it is null or not, so I can read it.
I was trying to use `map()` function but I can't set some sort of filter to only execute the annonymous function when it is NOT null.

I managed to do something like this:

```
let result = Object.values(arr).map(function(row){
  if(row['xyz'] != null) {
    console.log(row['xyz_id']);
  }
});
```

what If I want a new array containing ONLY `xyz_id` ? Is there a shorter version ?

Second case:

There are more than 1 value inside `xyz` and it's NOT "named".

```
let arr = [{  
    id : 1,
    usr : 'pimba',
    xyz: null
  },
  {
    id  : 2,
    usr : 'aloha',
    xyz: {
     xyz_id: {"value1Here", "Value2Here"}      
    }    
  },
  {
    id  : 3,
    age : 'pruu',
    xyz: null
  }];
```

Comment: Do you want a new array, where it's filtered to only contain objects where xyz is not null, or do you just want to flag it with a boolean somehow?

Comment: @JimmyHedström Hi ! A new array where each value is `xyz_id` value.

Comment: `let result = arr.filter(x => x.xyz).map(x => {...});`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you want to map the array only for the elements that have not-null `xyz` property. One option is using both `.filter` and `.map` methods. Another option is using the `.reduce` method:

```
let result = arr.reduce(function(ret, row) {
   // assuming `xyz` can be only `null` or an object
   if ( row.xyz !== null ) {
     ret.push(row.xyz.xyz_id);
   }
   return ret;
}, []);
```

Comment: Worked amazingly! Just didn't understand the reduce second parameter `[]`. Why is that ?

Comment: @PlayHardGoPro That's the initial value for the `.reduce` method. Check [the MDN entry for the `Array.prototype.reduce` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) for more information.

Comment: Thanks ! One last thing... Does the `Push()` function will push it even if you have something like this: `xyz: [
"value1Here",
"Value2Here"
]` ? Updated the question with an example.

Comment: @PlayHardGoPro `Array.prototype.push` can push any value. Arrays can have array elements. If you want to have a flattened array you can use the `Array.prototype.concat` method: `ret = ret.concat(row.xyz)`

Answer (score 2):

You might want to look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

```
const notNull = arr.filter(elm => elm.xyz !== null);
```

Comment: This would not filter out elements where `elm.xyz === undefined`. You could simplify it to `arr.filter(elm => elm.xyz)` to achieve this.

Comment: You could use `!=` instead of `!==` if you just wanted to rule out `null` and `undefined`. These two values are `==` to each other, and to no other values.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var a = {one: 1, two: null, three: 3, four: true}
var y = []
let scan = (obj) => { 
  Object.keys(obj).forEach(x => {
    if (obj[x] === null) {
       console.log('Its null')
    } else { 
       // Extend here to datatypes
      y.push(obj[x])
    }
  });
}
scan(a)
console.log(y)
```